# what is local key in laravel eloquent

Tags: sql, database, laravel

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships

what does local key mean in this thing? does it mean primary key of the table? or what? for example in this code

```
return $this->hasOne('Phone', 'foreign_key');

return $this->hasOne('Phone', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

Answer (score 9):

`local_key` is the primary key of your table. You only need to specify it if your primary key is not called `id` AND you do not have the `$primaryKey` property set in your model.

Comment: This isn't 100% accurate. You only need to set `local_key` if you want to use a column other than what Laravel recognizes as your table's primary key. By default this is indeed `id`, but if you've already set the `$primaryKey` attribute to, say, `foo_id`, there's no need to specify `foo_id` as the `local_key`.

Comment: @Rikaelus thanks I modified the answer a bit.

Answer (score 4):

I believe everything is written in the doc:

> ake note that Eloquent assumes the foreign key of the relationship based on the model name. In this case, Phone model is assumed to use a user_id foreign key. If you wish to override this convention, you may pass a second argument to the hasOne method. Furthermore, you may pass a third argument to the method to specify which local column that should be used for the association:

Which basically means that 'local_key' is the name of the table column in your db which is responsible to match the related entity (phone) with your current entity (user).

If you have a look at the db, I'm sure you'll find a table user with a phone_id column, try to change it to something else (like "phone" only) and your eloquent request will crash. Then change your call to `return $this->hasOne('Phone', 'user_id', 'phone');` and this might work again.

Comment: I didn't understand can you tell me which one is the local key in this picture  http://oi61.tinypic.com/2mewz8x.jpg

Comment: Assuming `$this` is your movie entity, `'genre_id'` should be your local_key. I'm not sure what kind of schema it is supposed to be though, but I understand here that you have a Many-To-One relationship, so the section of the documentation you are referring to is not relevant. Please consider using mysql workbench or similar to output an EER diagram or so...

Comment: if genre_id is the local key so what is the foreign key

Comment: That's exactly what I told you, you have a many-to-one relationship, not a one-to-one, so you won't find your foreign-key...

Comment: now I'm confused, let me drink a beer, so what should I do?

Comment: please I need an answer

Comment: I have red the docs, but there is not any information about my problem

Comment: engineer Thomas please do something for my problem